# React Router: Issue with URL redirection in nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm facing an issue with URL redirection in my React app using React Router (v5.3.4). When I click on a product, I'm redirected to the product's page with a URL like `"http://localhost:3000/product/34"`.

However, when I click on a related product from that page, instead of updating the URL to `"http://localhost:3000/product/35"`,
it appends the new URL to the existing one, resulting in `"http://localhost:3000/product/34/product/35"`.

I've tried a few solutions including using `Link` component from React Router, modifying the URL using `window.location.href`, and utilizing the `useNavigate` hook, but none of them have resolved the issue.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my `Product` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`product/${product.id}`}>
      {/* Product content */}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

I also tried to troubleshoot the problem by modifying the code to use only the product ID in the `to` attribute of the `Link` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`${product.id}`}>
      {/* Product content */}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Now, when I click on a related product, the URL becomes `"http://localhost:3000/product/34/35"` instead of `"http://localhost:3000/product/34/product/35"` as it was initially.

Could anyone provide any guidance/suggestions or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Use an ***absolute*** path, e.g. one that starts with a leading `"/"` character so the new path **is not** appended to the current URL path as a ***relative*** link.

Examples:

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>
      {/* Product content */}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

```
import { Link, generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={generatePath("/product/:productId", { productId: product.id })}>
      {/* Product content */}
    </Link>
  );
};
```